# Embed other code to Wordpress whitout using theme css files

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress theme, and it looks good now, however, I want to add a custom html form to it. But when I put the code in it whith path to its own css and js. The form looks terrible because of the css from the theme.

Is there any plugin or option to fix this or do I need to do it by an other way?

I looked everywhere on the internet but couldt find any solution.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks alot.

Comment: There's nothing to fix actually, this is the expected behavior for CSS. You just need to overwrite the theme's styles with your custom CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS means cascading stylesheets, and that's because the CSS from the page cascades downwards onto all the elements on the page. You either have to manually reset the CSS before it hits your form, or you need to embed your form as an `iframe` to avoid the cascade.

Answer (score 1):

Theme and bootstrap css will override input fields with ton's of styles. You don't have much options but to find and "ran over" problematic styles with your own. 
Use !important only if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I used !important but for the rest its a problem.